# Plex keeps needing permission to update library on ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: 18.04, server, permissions, chown, plex

So im still a ubuntu noob so im not very expirienced. I'm currently using plex and everytime i download something and transfer it to the right folder plex can't see the file but when i use chown or chmod on the folder, it does show up. Is there a way where i don't have to do that everytime?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, Plex runs as a different user (not you).

Let's take a look at a typical home directory:

```
me@plex:~$ ls -l /home/me
total 85225
drwxr-xr-x 7 me   me         14 Feb  2 14:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root        3 Dec 28 21:56 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me   me        141 Feb  2 14:24 Videos
```

No other users can read my Videos directory...including the Plex user.

There are several ways to solve the problem.

**One way is to create a new *group*** that Plex can access. Then chgrp (change group) when you add files to that folder.

```
  --- One time ---
$ sudo addgroup videos                 // Create group 
$ sudo adduser plex videos             // Let Plex see the group
$ sudo chgrp plex /home/me/Videos      // Let Plex see the directory

  --- Ongoing ---
$ sudo chgrp plex /home/me/Videos/whatever_video.mkv  // Change group of one file
$ sudo chgrp plex /home/me/Videos/*                   // Change group of ALL files
         // WARNING: Use '*' with caution. A typo could be disastrous.
```

**Another way is to give Plex access to ALL your files**. This is a shortcut for beginners who are still learning how Linux works. However, it's generally a Bad Idea for lots of reasons to let applications muck with your files over the long term.

```
$ sudo adduser plex me    // Add plex to the 'me' group. (Yes, YOU have a group)
                          // Your group's name is identical to YOUR username.
```

Of course, it's also a Bad Idea to store multi-user media in your own Home directory - you should eventually move multi-user data to a directory to /var, where that data belongs. But that's an answer for a different question and a different time.